# How to automatically manage joomla featured articles?

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, article-manager

I use the [Joomla FeedGator extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/feedgator) to import rss feeds from blogs. I set FeedGator to put generated articles as featured articles.

I want to have only the latest articles from each feed as featured articles (I have one category by feed). So old articles must be unfeatured when new articles are imported by FeedGator.

FeedGator does not do that.

So how to have automatically only the latest article of each category (= feed) as featured article ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve it is running a MySQL query, after running FeedGator cron job command. In this way, you can define a filter for "old articles" and unfeature them.

Otherwise, you would have to modify FeedGator source code.

Comment: Ok, if I understand well, there is no way to do that without specific coding. I will try with SQL query. I prefer not to modify FeedGator. It works well. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, that's the idea